# вот такая ошибка в коде Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

Вот такая ошибка в коде:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/reffe318/public_html/prote cted/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 426

Не могу сам решить. Помогите!

Вот код, где ошибка:

```
function class_uses_recursive($class)
{
    $results =[];
    foreach (array_merge([$class => $class]), class_parents($class)) as $class) {
        $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
    }

    return array_unique($results);
}
```

Место, на которое указывает ошибка:

```
$results =[];
```

после исправления

```
$results = array();
foreach (array_merge(($class => $class)), class_parents($class)) as $class)
{
    $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
}

return array_unique($results);
```

> syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW  on line 427

это тут думаю 
        foreach (array_merge(($class => $class))

после исправления

```
$results = array();
foreach array_merge(array($class => $class), class_parents($class))
```

Comment: а php какой? ваша версия такой синтаксис не поддерживает, используйте array: `$results = array();`, ну и в foreach тоже смените. А лучше будет php обновить, тогда и менять ничего не надо будет

Comment: версия php 5.4 неужели ее надо обновить? попробую обновить ,а foreach это о чем?

Comment: а точно 5.4? Он должен поддерживать, раз ошибка - значит другая версия срабатывает. Какие еще версии установлены? Про foreach - там тоже короткий синтаксис используется: `[$class => $class]`

Comment: изменения на $results = array(); не к чему не привели. появилась еще ошибка T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Comment: вы в вопросе эту информацию приведите, я же не знаю как вы заменили, может вы неправильно заменили

Comment: поправил в вопросе. не знаю уже как с этим бороться.

Comment: ну вот, я же говорил не правильно вставили в foreach, надо было вместо `[$class => $class]` делать `array($class => $class)` Только у вас сейчас еще одна проблема - там точно именно такой код? у вас одна скобка лишняя, должно быть так: `array_merge(array($class => $class), class_parents($class))`

Comment: изменил как вы указали  теперь ошибка такая   syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in

Comment: 1) вам надо учить php, у вас синтаксис foreach не верен (должен быть `foreach (...)` - вместо точек ваш код) 2) откатывайте изменения и обновляйте php. Это код larabel, а значит там куча таких мест, все не исправите. 3) либо, как вариант, используйте более старую версию laravel, которая с php 5.3 работает

Answer (score 2):

Вы скорее всего обновили `Laravel`. С версии `v5.1.0` этому фреймворку нужен `php: >=5.5.9`. Или разворачиваете проект на новом сервере со старым `php`.

### Вариант 1

Обновить `PHP` т.к. короткая запись массивов `[1,2,3]` появилась только в `php >= 5.4`. Проверить версию можно в консоли, набрав `php -v`, но лучше через веб сервер, т.к. интерпретаторов в ОС может стоять несколько. Создайте файл и откройте его в браузере со следующем содержимым:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

И смотрите версию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Вариант 2

Судя по директории `vendor` вы используете композер и можете легко откатить версию `Laravel`. Просто укажите в `composer.json` версию поддерживающую `php 5.4`:

```
"require":{
    ...
    "laravel/framework":"5.0.*"
    ...
}
```

Если на сервере есть разные сайты с одним http сервером, то лучше фреймворк откатить, или если есть хороший админ под рукой, то можно разные версии `php` для разных виртуальных хостов настроить. В остальных случаях лучше обновить `php`.

### PS

Вы так мучились с кусочком кода, что я не выдержал. Вот "правильный" (под 5.4) код:

```
function class_uses_recursive($class)
{
    $results = array();
    foreach (array_merge(array($class => $class), class_parents($class)) as $class) {
        $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
    }

    return array_unique($results);
}
```