# Ошибка HP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Tags: php

При запуске скрипта `crontab` ругается на функцию, которая приведена ниже.
Выдает ошибку -

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in"

в строке - `$params = array_merge([$value], array_slice( $args, 2, func_num_args() ) )`;

```
function array_group_by( array $array, $key ){
    if ( ! is_string( $key ) && ! is_int( $key ) && ! is_float( $key ) && ! is_callable( $key ) ) {
        trigger_error( 'array_group_by(): The key should be a string, an integer, or a callback', E_USER_ERROR );
        return null;
    }

    $func = ( is_callable( $key ) ? $key : null );
    $_key = $key;

    // Load the new array, splitting by the target key
    $grouped = array();
    foreach ( $array as $value ) {
        if ( is_callable( $func ) ) {
            $key = call_user_func( $func, $value );
        } elseif ( is_object( $value ) && isset( $value->{ $_key } ) ) {
            $key = $value->{ $_key };
        } elseif ( isset( $value[ $_key ] ) ) {
            $key = $value[ $_key ];
        } else {
            continue;
        }

        $grouped[ $key ][] = $value;
    }

    // Recursively build a nested grouping if more parameters are supplied
    // Each grouped array value is grouped according to the next sequential key
    if ( func_num_args() > 2 ) {
        $args = func_get_args();

        foreach ( $grouped as $key => $value ) {
            $params = array_merge([$value], array_slice( $args, 2, func_num_args() ) );
            $grouped[ $key ] = call_user_func_array( 'array_group_by', $params );
        }
    }

    return $grouped;
}
```

Comment: пхп то какой версии? попробуйте поменять `[$value]` на `array($value)`

Comment: версия 5.6 спасибо заработало!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574669/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected)

Comment: либо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475873/223826

Comment: либо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525532/223826

Comment: либо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476304/223826